# Error when comparing string value and string value from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, compare

I'm trying to compare 2 values, one coming from post data and the other one coming from an array, the weird thing is, when I compare them, all of the records show that they are not equal but some of the values have equal values:

What I actually need to do is to unset those values that are not equal in the post data sent.

```
$a = $_POST['time']; (Value is 01:03)

$testarray = array("12:30","01:03","03:30");

for($x = 0; $x < count($testarray);$x++){
  if($a === $testarray[$x]){
    echo "ok";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "not";
  }
}
```

All of the my results are showing not, even though there is a similar value on one of the contents in the array.

What seems to be the problem here? I've check the values and the data types are both string.

Comment: `if(in_array($a, $testarray))`. no need of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [in_array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp)

```
$a = $_POST['time']; //(Value is 01:03)

$testarray = array("12:30","01:03","03:30");


if( in_array($a, $testarray))
{
    echo "ok";
}
else
{
    echo "not";
}
```

Comment: this will still work even if the array is a multidimensional one right?

Comment: ya. Its search entire array

Answer (score 1):

Simple use **[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)** to  Checks if a value exists in an array

```
 $a = $_POST['time'];
 $testarray = array("12:30","01:03","03:30");

if (in_array($a, $testarray))
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }
```